# "TypeError: can't quote" when using custom types and the attributes API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running into a problem when trying to use the Attributes API to allow a custom type in my ActiveRecord models. I can get everything working until I try to access a relationship. When I do that, I receive a `TypeError: can't quote` error. This appears to be caused by `ActiveRecord` when it tries to "quote" the attribute. I'm assuming it serializes the attribute before quoting. Does anyone see something I am missing?

Model:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
   attribute :my_attr, :my_custom
   has_many :others, primary_key: :my_attr
end
```

Attribute Type:

```
class MyCustomType < ActiveRecord::Type::String

  def deserialize(value)
    MyCustom.new(value)
  end

  def cast(value)
    MyCustom.new(value)
  end

  def serialize(value)
    value.to_s
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you add a stacktrace?

Comment: There isn't much a trace. It just points to the line that calls the relationship. e.g. "my_class.others"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, Add the custom type to the attribute on the corresponding class. This will tell rails how to handle that attribute on the two different classes when dealing with relationships.

```
class Other < ActiveRecord::Base
   attribute :my_attr, :my_custom
   belongs_to :my_class, primary_key: :my_attr
end
```